# Fixing a malformed UTF-8 string

Tags: php, json, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I've gotten a custom JSON api for my school, so I can look up homework. Let's call the result string **$result**. Unfortunately it seems like the UTF-8 I'm getting back is malformed. Running [mb_check_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php) confirms that the string is UTF-8 encoded, however I'm not able to decode the JSON string.

When I use [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on my string, it's returning NULL and [json_last_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) gives me the error "**JSON_ERROR_UTF8**" = 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded'.

using `iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT", $result)`
is throwing a PHP notice:

> [iconv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php): Detected an illegal character in input string in
> C:\wamp\www\Tietgen\homework.php

Using `iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $result)` instead, is giving me a JSON result back, however it is being cut off in the middle (presumably at the same point where TRANSLIT is detecting the illegal character), giving me the JSON error

> Unexpected control character found

Doing `json_decode(utf8_encode($result))` is returning `NULL` aswell, and gives me this JSON error:

> Syntax error, malformed JSON

echoing utf8_encode($result) is being cut off aswell.

I've got a program running on my comp called JSON Viewer. When I paste the JSON from the original source (the api, I'm accessing), it's working perfectly in JSON Viewer.
[image]
This looks like the JSON is valid.

I've been stuck with this for a while, is there any way to fix an malformed UTF-8 string? if so, how? :)

Unfortunately I cannot share the API :/

Also, I can see that iconv is quite resource intensive, is there maybe a better method? :)

Comment: In that case the "json" API does not actually return standard JSON. Maybe you need to filter it in some way before you can parse it. Without seeing the data it's impossible to say more.

Comment: Updated again ^^ If the json is invalid, how is JSON Viewer able retrieve everything. My chrome extension is also able to recognize it :), it's first after I work it through my code it's messed up ^^

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing what your script is receiving. Maybe the server uses compression, which chrome handles transparently but your http client doesn't.

Comment: That makes sense, is there any way I can show you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the @Jazerix problem is the following, I thing that probably someone has the same issue:

I get data from a MySQL database to a PHP array. I set columns in MySQL as `utf8_unicode_ci` and I set charset in PHP: `$db->exec($sql, null, 'utf8');`

I get error

> Syntax error, malformed JSON

Because I have one enum column in database, and that column doesn't have UTF-8 coding. I had one option called **'Campaña'**, and that was the key, 'ñ' character.

Hope it helps someone.